# Downloading a video from an API in React using Axios creates an empty mp4 file

Tags: reactjs, api, video, axios

I have a backend api that returns a video (verified route in Postman) but when trying to implement a "download video" button, it downloads an empty file

I've tried multiple implementations with at best identical results but here is the current code:

```
const handleDownloadVideo = async () => {
    const axios = require('axios');

    const config = {
        method: 'get',
        url: `http://localhost:3001/api/v1/render/video/${UUID}/download/`,
        headers: { 
            'Authorization': 'Bearer {token}', 
            'responseType': 'blob',
            'maxContentLength': Infinity,
            'maxBodyLength': Infinity
        }
    };

    axios(config)
    .then((response) => {
        const link = document.createElement('a');
        link.target = '_blank';
        link.download = `${UUID}.mp4`;
        link.href = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data], { type: "video/mp4" }));
        link.click();
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
};
```

I wouldn't expect this to be a difficult task and yet have been struggling with it for multiple days now. Can anybody explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this might solve the problem, but your request config `responseType`, `maxContentLength` and `maxBodyLength` should be outside the header object.

```js
const config = {
    method: 'get',
    url: `http://localhost:3001/api/v1/render/video/${UUID}/download/`,
    responseType: 'blob',
    maxContentLength: Infinity,
    maxBodyLength: Infinity
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {token}'
    }
};
```

Comment: It's a partial answer that led me to the correct path. Thank you. Appending this after the request resulted in functioning code



                `const response = await axios(config);
  const blobData: Blob = response.data;

  //Create download link
  const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blobData);
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = blobURL;
  link.download = `${UUID}.mp4`;
  link.click();`

edit: How do I get the code to format correctly here?